# Issues with Mapping Entities in Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

[image: e]

The above shown is my database design and wanted to get login_info along with the person entity, how I have mapped my entities are as follows.

**Class Person**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {
    // Constructor and other fields
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "person", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private LoginInfo loginInfo;
    // Getter & Setter
}
```

**Class Login Info**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "login_info")
public class LoginInfo {
    // Constructor and other fields
    @OneToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Person person;
    // Getter & Setter
}
```

By the above code, I'm able to get Person Object into LoginInfo list, I want to get LoginInfo into Person Object, I have tried various examples and code snippet from the StackOverflow as well as from the internet. Also tried code vice-versa but always getting Person into LoginInfo, can you guys please help where I'm not getting this mapping and at which point I'm wrong.

Comment: Your `mappedBy` is pointing at the wrong thing. It should be pointing at `"person"`, which is the name of the Java attribute in the target class that holds the reference back to the current class.

Comment: @JonK I have already checked that, it was a mistake here, but in code, it is pointing to the person as I've updated the question.

Comment: @HP's411 How you are fetching the LoginInfo entity?  Are you getting any error while fetching it?

Comment: @Shashank I'm just fetching persons, and login_info should be included in it. No, there is nothing in console, in fact I'm getting response too, but without login_info into person object

Comment: In @JoinColumn(name = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false) (may be a typo) you are mapping foreign_key to id column. In order to share primary keys you need to add @MapsId Over the association. Look at this article on shared primary key for OneToOne associations.[shared primary key](https://thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-same-primary-key-one-to-one-association/)